# emacs: visual-line-mode and fill-paragraph

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am now using Emacs 23 with visual-line-mode turned of for text editing but keep hitting M-q out of habit (thus adding hard-wrapping line endings...). I wonder if there is a way to add a conditional to disable fill-paragraph (or remove the binding to M-q) for modes in which visual-line-mode is turned on, but to re-enable it for those in which I am still using the auto-fill-mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(defun maybe-fill-paragraph (&optional justify region)
  "Fill paragraph at or after point (see `fill-paragraph').

Does nothing if `visual-line-mode' is on."
  (interactive (progn
         (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
         (list (if current-prefix-arg 'full) t)))
  (or visual-line-mode
      (fill-paragraph justify region)))

;; Replace M-q with new binding:
(global-set-key "\M-q" 'maybe-fill-paragraph)
```

Instead of using `global-set-key`, you can also rebind `M-q` only in specific modes.  (Or, you could change the global binding, and then bind `M-q` back to `fill-paragraph` in a specific mode.)  Note that many modes are autoloaded, so their keymap may not be defined until the mode is activated.  To set a mode-specific binding, I usually use a function like this:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
  (defun cjm-fix-text-mode ()
    (define-key text-mode-map "\M-q" 'maybe-fill-paragraph)
    (remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'cjm-fix-text-mode)))
```

(The `remove-hook` isn't strictly necessary, but the function only needs to run once.)

Comment: globally setting `M-q` is evil, because it affects all modes. if you have to do this, use `substitute-key-definition` (or use defadvice or fset instead)

Comment: But that was the whole point.  M-q is already a global binding.  He wanted it rebound to a function that checked visual-line-mode.

Comment: Hmmm... also a great option... Global setting of M-q may be dangerous but the function is simple enough (and elegant) that its consequences are predictable?

Comment: ok you won. I thought is was only bound in text-like modes, but I noticed it is bound everywhere, it's `fill-paragraph-function` that's doing the magic in the other modes...

Comment: Thanks for your post and edit! [So I am relatively new at this but wouldn't 
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(lambda () (define-key text-mode-map "\M-q" 'maybe-fill-paragraph))) also do it?]

Comment: Yes, that will work.  I just happen to prefer using a real named function instead of an anonymous one.

Comment: @crippledlambda each major-mode has one keymap.  If you add a function to modify it every time the major-mode is used, it's not very efficient.  @cjm instead of the `add-hook` `remove-hook` hackiness use `eval-after-load`

Answer (score 5):

you can use an advise for this.

For your .emacs:

```
(defadvice fill-paragraph (around disable-for-visual-line-mode activate)
  (unless visual-line-mode
    ad-do-it))
```

This will change fill-paragraph to do nothing when visual-line-mode is on. You can also add an error if you prefer that.

Comment: Note that this will completely disable `fill-paragraph` when visual-line-mode is on, even if it's being called from an elisp function. You probably don't want to be that drastic.

Comment: I agree, very pretty... but cjm has a point... though I don't know how often fill-paragraph is called from within elisp functions.

Comment: (I love defadvice though because you can also turn it off without rebooting emacs)

Comment: **Usage Note:** Advice is useful for altering the behavior of existing calls to an existing function. If you want the new behavior for new calls, or for key bindings, you should define a new function (or a new command) which uses the existing function. (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions)

Comment: Re: "(I love defadvice though because you can also turn it off without rebooting emacs)"
You can also bind M-q back to fill-paragraph (either globally or in a specific mode) without restarting Emacs.

Comment: So one point where I saw this might cause conflict was org-mode, where I do use visual-line-mode, but it looks like fill-paragraph is used internally to arrange the table layout. 

org.el:

;; We use our own fill-paragraph function, to make sure that tables
;; and fixed-width regions are not wrapped.  That function will pass
;; through to `fill-paragraph' when appropriate.

so I guess I'm a bit queasy about modifying 'fill-paragraph' directly - though it certainly is the sweetest of eye candies!

Answer (score 2):

visual-line-mode has its own keymap: `visual-line-mode-map`. I recommend rebinding M-q only in that keymap.

The map is defined as part of startup, so you don’t need eval-after-load. Just disable the binding in that mode:

```
(define-key visual-line-mode-map [remap fill-paragraph] 'ignore)
```

Comment: `ignore` is the canonical "take any arguments and do nothing" command.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @phils, I’ve edited my answer. (Ed: previously I was defining my own noop function instead of 'ignore.)